# Hibernate: To return sum of specific column grouped by date

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

I need to write a criteria query to retrieve a sum of `amount` column grouped by a specific `date`. The table I mean consist of the following columns:

```
  id      partner_id    amount         date       platform_id
serial     integer    numeric(13.4)  timestamp      integer
```

Hibernate mapping does in the following way:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private int id;

@ManyToOne(targetEntity = Partner.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="partner_id")
private Partner partner;

@Column(name = "amount")
private BigDecimal amount;

@Column(name = "date")
private Date date;

@ManyToOne(targetEntity = Platform.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="platform_id")
private Platform platform;
```

I've written the following query:

```
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(DailyProfit.class)
        .add(Restrictions.eq("partner", partner))
        .add(Restrictions.eq("platform", platform))
        .add(Restrictions.between("date", from, to));

criteria.setProjection(Projections.groupProperty("date"));
criteria.setProjection(Projections.sum("amount").as("DailySum"));
```

But the `criteria.list()` returns `[1119950.8300, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]`. That is absolutely not what I'm expected. Could you explain that result and help me to fix criteria query?

Answer (score 0):

Your code was perfect

criteria.list() - will return List of object (Collections). You should use index or iterator  to get the value of result.

Or

Integer amount= (Integer) criteria.uniqueResult();

Comment: But I need to recieve a list of pairs (date, sum) rather then I've done. May I not understand the result criteria has returned?